# Laravel - Public variable in controller

Tags: laravel

I want to have one public variable `$users = User::all();` so i could use it in different methods inside controller and it doesn't work this way:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;

class AdminController extends Controller
{

    public $users = User::all();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }


    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.index');
    }

    public function showUsers()
    {
        
        return view('admin.users', compact('users'));
    }
}
```

i get this error: Constant expression contains invalid operations

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the assignment into the `__construct()` function instead:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;

class AdminController extends Controller
{

    public $users;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->users = User::all();
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }


    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.index');
    }

    public function showUsers()
    {
        $users = $this->users;
        return view('admin.users', compact('users'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Undefined variable: users in view

Comment: in view i have only {{$users}}

Comment: @lewis4u you cannot pass class variables to views directly. Try `$users = $this->users` first and then `return view('admin.users', compact('users'));`

Comment: yes, this works....hmm how can i make it better....my method looks now like this     public function showUsers()
    {
        $users = $this->users;
     return view('admin.users', compact('users'));
    }

Comment: i could throw everything away and just declare the variable in that method like $users = User::all(); But then i would have to do it for every method that uses users as variable

Comment: Why don't you just use the `Users::all()` method as and when you need it, rather than assigning it to another method?

Comment: I thought i could declare it once in controller and just use it inside controller and with views

Comment: You can use it in any view using something like `view('admin.users',['users' => User::all()]`

Comment: You can use [repositories](https://laracasts.com/lessons/repositories-simplified) if you really look for the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `$users` in your constructor:

```
<?php

public $users;

public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->users = User::all();
}
```

Comment: Awww ... You were 44 seconds ahead of me Lol

Comment: Happens all the time ;)

Comment: I blame the SO markdown ... Having to use spaces for code blocks :/

Comment: I agree. It's quite annoying.